# Craft 3: Get Data from a custom Table via createCommand()

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, database, query

In Craft 2 you could creat a query with:

`craft()->db->createCommand()->select()` .... etc.

But in Craft 3 there is no `select()` Method in `Craft::$app->db->createCommand()`.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use either an [activeRecord](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record)  for it

```
$customer = Customer::find() 
    ->where(['id' => 123]) 
    ->one();
```

Or a [query](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder)

```
$rows = (new \craft\db\Query()) 
    ->select(['id', 'email']) 
    ->from('user') 
    ->where(['last_name' => 'Smith']) 
    ->limit(10)
     ->all();
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how would you then return the $rows array to your twig template?

Comment: @JimPannell  It depends on what you are doing. If you call this function via `Variable` you can just return it. If you call it via controller request you can render it `return $this->renderTemplate('path/to/template' ['data' => $rows])` if it is an ajax request you need to encode it to json  within your Controller `return $this->asJson(['data' => $rows]);` It's hard to tell without further information

Comment: Thanks @Robin-Schambach. It's actually in a service file (I understood this is where most of my DB calls should be in Craft 3).

Comment: Services always only return it variables and controllers proceed those values and pass them to Twig/JS/whatever

Comment: I'm new to Craft dev work and have been finding the lack of Craft 3 examples and documentation really hard going. Your comments help a lot - thanks.

Comment: Usually the source code is the best example you can find. You could join us in slack as well